# What's the matter with my GTK here?

Tags: gtk, glib

Every time I run a gtk program such `nautilus`, `synaptic`, those kind of appears again and again but those programs can still run:

```
(gnome-terminal:589): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Two different plugins tried to register 'BasicEngineFc'.

(gnome-terminal:589): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

...
```

What's the matter with it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you need not worry as long as the concerned programs run as intended.

You can look at this: [A lot of `gtk-warnings` in terminal. Is this serious?](https://askubuntu.com/q/205349/25656).